# Gobject's function G_TYPE_INSTANCE_GET_PRIVATE is deprecated

Tags: gtk3, dbus, gobject

I'd like to build dbusmenu library, but I can't because the function in the title is deprecated. All programmers should use G_ADD_PRIVATE instead. Of course I found a workaround, but I'd like to fix the code (this is a library used in Debian, MATE etc.)

I assume I can't replace macro, this would be too easy and it does not make sense :).. So, is there anyone who can provide me with an example how to use G_ADD_PRIVATE in GObjects? Thanks

This is an example of the deprecated code:

```
static void
dbusmenu_defaults_init (DbusmenuDefaults *self)
{
    self->priv = DBUSMENU_DEFAULTS_GET_PRIVATE(self);

    self->priv->types = g_hash_table_new_full(g_str_hash, g_str_equal, g_free, (GDestroyNotify)g_hash_table_destroy);
}
```

where

```
#define DBUSMENU_DEFAULTS_GET_PRIVATE(o) \
(G_TYPE_INSTANCE_GET_PRIVATE ((o), DBUSMENU_TYPE_DEFAULTS, DbusmenuDefaultsPrivate))
```

Answer (score 0):

There’s an example in [the documentation for `G_ADD_PRIVATE`](https://docs.gtk.org/gobject/func.ADD_PRIVATE.html).

Answer (score 0):

I did not find the documentation helpful, (1) the information contained was wrong, and (2) it did not work.

I found this example that someone did to update an existing source code [libreoffice src code change](https://gerrit.libreoffice.org/c/core/+/79663/).

The code I was working on already had the G_ADD_PRIVATE() implemented, but it was still using the G_TYPE_INSTANCE_GET_PRIVATE() function.

from:

```
G_DEFINE_TYPE_WITH_CODE (GLOActionGroup, g_lo_action_group, G_TYPE_OBJECT,
    G_IMPLEMENT_INTERFACE (G_TYPE_ACTION_GROUP, g_lo_action_group_iface_init));
```

to:

```
G_DEFINE_TYPE_WITH_CODE (GLOActionGroup, g_lo_action_group, G_TYPE_OBJECT,
    G_ADD_PRIVATE(GLOActionGroup)
    G_IMPLEMENT_INTERFACE (G_TYPE_ACTION_GROUP, g_lo_action_group_iface_init));
```

and from:

```
g_lo_action_group_init (GLOActionGroup *group)
{
    group->priv = G_TYPE_INSTANCE_GET_PRIVATE (group, G_TYPE_LO_ACTION_GROUP, GLOActionGroupPrivate);
}
```

to:

```
g_lo_action_group_init (GLOActionGroup *group)
{
    group->priv = g_lo_action_group_get_instance_private (group);
}
```